# Is there a known inconsistent behavior in C++ std::vector multiplication?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, c++11, debugging

I am translating a Python code to C++.

I am having problem in the snippet below. These two codes should be the same thing, but tehy are giving me different outputs.

I am lost. The error begins when `k=1`. What is happening, where is the error?

If that matters: I am compiling the C++ code with the IDE [Eclipse Parallel Mars](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-parallel-application-developers/mars2), windows 10, MinGW.

### Python 3.5:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(([2,-1,0,0],[-1,1.5,-0.5,0],[0,-0.5,0.75,-0.25],[0,0,-0.25,0.25]))
b = np.array(([0,0,0,1]))
for k in range(len(b)-1,-1,-1):
    p = 0
    print("")
    print("k = ", k)
    print("b[k] = ", b[k])
    for m in range(k+1, len(b)):
        print("m = ", m)
        print("b[m] = ", b[m])
        print("a[k,m] = ",a[k,m])
        p += a[k,m] * b[m];
        print("p = ", p)

    b[k] = (b[k] - p)/a[k,k];
```

### C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector< std::vector<double> > a = { {2,-1,0,0}, {-1,1.5,-0.5,0},
                {0,-0.5,0.75,-0.25}, {0,0,-0.25,0.25} };
    std::vector<double> b = {0,0,0,1};
    double p;
    for (int k = b.size()-1; k >= 0; --k) {
        p = 0;
        std::cout << std::endl << "k = " << k << std::endl;
        std::cout << "b[k] = " << b[k] << std::endl;
        for (size_t m = k+1; m < b.size(); ++m) {
            std::cout << "m = " << m << std::endl;
            std::cout << "b[m] = " << b[m] << std::endl;
            std::cout << "a[k][m] = " << a[k][m] << std::endl;
            p += a[k][m] * b[m];
            std::cout << "p = " << p << std::endl;
        }
        b[k] = (b[k] - p)/a[k][k];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

## Output

### Python 3.5:

```
k =  3
b[k] =  1

k =  2
b[k] =  0
m =  3
b[m] =  4
a[k,m] =  -0.25
p =  -1.0

k =  1
b[k] =  0
m =  2
b[m] =  1
a[k,m] =  -0.5
p =  -0.5
m =  3
b[m] =  4
a[k,m] =  0.0
p =  -0.5

k =  0
b[k] =  0
m =  1
b[m] =  0
a[k,m] =  -1.0
p =  0.0
m =  2
b[m] =  1
a[k,m] =  0.0
p =  0.0
m =  3
b[m] =  4
a[k,m] =  0.0
p =  0.0
```

### C++11:

```
k = 3
b[k] = 1

k = 2
b[k] = 0
m = 3
b[m] = 4
a[k][m] = -0.25
p = -1

k = 1
b[k] = 0
m = 2
b[m] = 1.33333
a[k][m] = -0.5
p = -0.666667
m = 3
b[m] = 4
a[k][m] = 0
p = -0.666667

k = 0
b[k] = 0
m = 1
b[m] = 0.444444
a[k][m] = -1
p = -0.444444
m = 2
b[m] = 1.33333
a[k][m] = 0
p = -0.444444
m = 3
b[m] = 4
a[k][m] = 0
p = -0.444444
```

Comment: In your Python, `b` has an integer dtype rather than floating-point.

Comment: Side note: `reversed(range(0, len(b))` is not really less efficient and seems much more readable.

Comment: @cdhowie Not in Python 3+, `(b[k] - p)/a[k,k]` will be floating-point. It is, however, cast to an integer once assigned to `b[k]` as implied by user235711.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Python code is defective.  It is truncating numbers, resulting in integer values where you expected a float with a fractional component.

In particular, `np.array(([0,0,0,1]))` is creating a numpy array with an integral data type, which means when you assign to `b[k]`, the floating point value is being truncated to an integer.  From [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) for `numpy.array()` concerning the optional `dtype` argument (emphasis mine):

> The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then **the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence.**

Since you have provided only integer values in the input array, numpy infers that you are wanting to create an array of integers.

The C++ code is correct.

When I fix your Python code to use floating-point values everywhere, the output matches the C++ version:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(([2.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0],[-1.0,1.5,-0.5,0.0],[0.0,-0.5,0.75,-0.25],[0.0,0.0,-0.25,0.25]))
b = np.array(([0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]))
for k in range(len(b)-1,-1,-1):
    p = 0
    print("")
    print("k = ", k)
    print("b[k] = ", b[k])
    for m in range(k+1, len(b)):
        print("m = ", m)
        print("b[m] = ", b[m])
        print("a[k,m] = ",a[k,m])
        p += a[k,m] * b[m];
        print("p = ", p)

    b[k] = (b[k] - p)/a[k,k];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the `dtype` as `'float64'` when creating your array `b`:

`b = np.array(([0,0,0,1]), dtype='float64')`

The output is then the following, which matches your C++ program:

```
k = 3
b[k] = 1.0

k = 2
b[k] = 0.0
m = 3
b[m] = 4.0
a[k,m] = -0.25
p = -1.0

k = 1
b[k] = 0.0
m = 2
b[m] = 1.3333333333333333
a[k,m] = -0.5
p = -0.66666666666666663
m = 3
b[m] = 4.0
a[k,m] = 0.0
p = -0.66666666666666663

k = 0
b[k] = 0.0
m = 1
b[m] = 0.44444444444444442
a[k,m] = -1.0
p = -0.44444444444444442
m = 2
b[m] = 1.3333333333333333
a[k,m] = 0.0
p = -0.44444444444444442
m = 3
b[m] = 4.0
a[k,m] = 0.0
p = -0.44444444444444442
```